# Referencing child objects in a javascript array for Express API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express

I have this dummy data:

```
var data = [{
    articles : [{
        id : '0',
        url : 'foo',
        title : 'Foo',
        body : 'some foo bar',
        category : 'foo',
        tags : [
            'foo'
        ]
    }, {
        id : '1',
        url : 'foo-bar',
        title : 'Foo bar',
        body : 'more foo bar',
        category : 'foo',
        tags : [
            'foo', 'bar'
        ]
    }, {
        id : '2',
        url : 'foo-bar-baz',
        title : 'Foo bar baz',
        body : 'more foo bar baz',
        category : 'foo',
        tags : [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'baz'
        ]
    }]
}, {
    users : [{
        name: 'Admin'
    }, {
        name: 'User'
    }]
}];
```

I have a router which I want to request only the matching article with it's ID from the articles:

```
// Grab single article
// http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/0
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  if(data.length <= req.params.id || req.params.id < 0) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    return res.send('Error 404: No quote found');
  };
  var q = data[req.params.id];
  res.json(q);
});
```

Using the following URL `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/0` returning the articles group but not the first article.

Thank You for your help!

Comment: try with `data[0].articles[req.params.id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to match the "id" and not just the index in the array, you should do something like this:

```
var articles = data[0].articles;
var q = articles.filter(function (article) {
   return article.id === req.params.id;
});

res.json(q[0]);
```

Comment: Thank You! This is very nice solution! Now I'm able to target the "url" field too which is great!

Comment: How can I access a nested object like the `tags` with `/articles/tags/:id` url? `return article.tags[0] === req.params.id;` returning the first article only.

Comment: `return article.tags.some(function(tagId) {
    return tagId === req.params.id;
});`

Comment: This is almost good, but only returning one result at a time. For example every 3 article have the tag `foo`, but in this case only the first article will be queried.

Comment: did you do it like this?:

`var articles = data[0].articles;
var qs = articles.filter(function (article) {
   return article.tags.some(function(tagId) { return tagId === req.params.id;});
});

res.json(qs);`

Comment: Awesome, It works,Thank You! I used `res.json(q[0]);` that's caused it.

Answer (score 1):

The 0th element in the outer array is the object that contains all the articles. First you'll need to drill down to the articles array: `data[0].articles`. Then to get just the object from the array with the id property that matches the id number you need, you could use the lo_dash library's `_.find()` function. https://lodash.com/docs#find

The call would look something like: `_.find(data[0].articles, {id:req.params.id});`